# How to have moving transitions animation between two panels?

Tags: gwt

I have two panels (`A` and `B`) in gwt.

First `A` is showing and `B` is hidden. If I click a button, `A` becomes hidden and `B` is shown.

However, I wish to have the `moving transitions animation` between two panels, i.e., if I click the button, `A` moves away and `B` moves in, etc.

Can I achieve that via gwt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can use [DeckPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckPanel.html) with setAnimationEnabled(boolean enable).

If you don't like DeckPanel, you can also create your own animation like that:

```
public class SlideAnimation extends Animation
{
    private final Widget widget;
    private boolean         opening;

    public SlideAnimation(Widget widget)
    {
        this.widget = widget;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onComplete()
    {
        if(! opening)
            this.widget.setVisible(false);

        DOM.setStyleAttribute(this.widget.getElement(), "height", "auto");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        opening = ! this.widget.isVisible();

        if(opening)
        {
            DOM.setStyleAttribute(this.widget.getElement(), "height", "0px");
            this.widget.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(double progress)
    {
        int scrollHeight = DOM.getElementPropertyInt(this.widget.getElement(), "scrollHeight");
        int height = (int) (progress * scrollHeight);
        if( !opening )
        {
            height = scrollHeight - height;
        }
        height = Math.max(height, 1);
        DOM.setStyleAttribute(this.widget.getElement(), "height", height + "px");
    }
}
```

and then add a handler to your button:

```
@UiHandler("myButton")
protected void handleClick(ClickEvent event)
{
    myAnimation.run(180); // myAnimation should be initialized in your constructor
}
```

This is just an example but I think you can do what you want  with some changes.

Comment: thanks. If I use DeckPanel, can I have the animation like iPhone sliding?

Comment: Unfortunately DockPanel doesn't allow to customize its animation. For your needs, I think you have to create your own animation...